# cell to matrix matching / map / cellOperations (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I cannot find the string equivalent of the finalAnswer using the data below.  Please, I cannot use if/for loops!  A final answer is preferred with each element as an array (i.e. the format of mainData)

```
mainData = {'IBM' [201] [1] ; 
            'GE' [403] [1] ; 
            'MSFT' [502] [3] ;
            'GM' [101] [2]       } ;

finalAns = [ 101 2 0.5; 403 1 0.6 ]                  ;

%% I tried doing this ->
temp = cell2mat(mainData(:,[2 3])) ;

tf = ismember(temp, finalAns(:,[1 2],'rows') ;
secIDs = mainData(tf) ;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want as an output? Are you trying to select only the rows of `mainData` whose second and third columns match entries in `finalAns`?

Comment: Thnx. I prefer the answer as: 'GM' [101] [2] [0.5] ; 'GE' [403] [1] 0.6]

Comment: OR -> 'GM' [101 2 0.5] ; 'GE' [403 1 0.6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the entries in each row of `mainData` that match those in `finalAns` (based on the last two columns of `mainData` and the first two columns of `finalAns`) and to get them in the same order that they appear in `finalAns` and with the last column of `finalAns` appended, you can do this:

```
>> temp = cell2mat(mainData(:,2:3));
>> [isThere,index] = ismember(finalAns(:,1:2),temp,'rows');
>> output = [mainData(index(isThere),:) num2cell(finalAns(isThere,3))]

output = 

    'GM'    [101]    [2]    [0.5000]
    'GE'    [403]    [1]    [0.6000]
```

The output is a 2-by-4 cell array with each value in a separate cell. If you want the last three columns to be collected in a vector, you can replace the calculation of `output` above with this:

```
>> temp = [temp(index(isThere),:) finalAns(isThere,3)];
>> output = [mainData(index(isThere),1) num2cell(temp,2)]

output = 

    'GM'    [1x3 double]
    'GE'    [1x3 double]
```

Note that now you have a 2-by-2 cell array where cells in the second column contain 1-by-3 double arrays.

Comment: Perfect! I needed the 2*4 cell array which now can be output to a .csv file.  Thanks so much 'gnovice'!